# remove extra lines from anchors

Tags: html, css

I want to remove these extra spacing from bottom and right from the below:

The result is different on IE and chrome, chrome has both spacing, IE has no spacing on bottom.

Could you guide what I am doing wrong? Maybe something to do with "display" css?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m_umair_85/nyaFz/4/)

Screenshot Chrome:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlRSC.png

Screenshot IE:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/msohg.png

Code:

```html
<footer>
<a class="tb-btn-s" style="color: #fff; background-color: #0064a9" href="/services/">service</a>
<a class="tb-btn-s" style="color: #fff; background-color: #0064a9" href="/services/">service</a>
<a class="tb-btn-s" style="color: #fff; background-color: #0064a9" href="/services/">service</a>
<a class="tb-btn-s" style="color: #fff; background-color: #0064a9" href="/services/">service</a>
<a class="tb-btn-s" style="color: #fff; background-color: #0064a9" href="/services/">service</a>
<a class="tb-btn-s" style="color: #fff; background-color: #0064a9" href="/services/">service</a>
<a class="tb-btn-s" style="color: #fff; background-color: #0064a9" href="/services/">service</a>
<a class="tb-btn-s" style="color: #fff; background-color: #0064a9" href="/services/">service</a>
<a class="tb-btn-s" style="color: #fff; background-color: #0064a9" href="/services/">service</a>
<a class="tb-btn-s" style="color: #fff; background-color: #0064a9" href="/services/">service</a>
    </footer>
```

Css:

```css
.tb-btn-s {
    zoom: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 5px;
    min-width: 42px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: visible;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 30px;
    min-width: 60px;
}
footer
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the spaces below the links, add `vertical-align:top;` to the `.tb-btn-s` class. To remove the spaces next to the links, remove the white space in your code.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nyaFz/6/)**

Comment: Thanks that worked, didn't notice the spacing in the anchors which fixed the right spacing!!

Answer (score 0):

just add `float:left;` in .tb-btn-s

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/nyaFz/7/)

Answer (score -1):

The side margin is because of inline-block
The bottom margin is because of lineheight

You can add this to the parent

```
word-spacing:-4px;
```

And reset it on the "a" to remove the margin from inline-block

```
word-spacing:0;
```

Also remove your line-height

http://jsfiddle.net/nyaFz/5/

Comment: word-spacing is unfortunately not cross browser and line-height not the right solution for the vertcal gap :(

Comment: i've been playing around with these long ago. to be cross browser it needed to be , for some : * - letter spacing:0;   *- wordspacing:0 *- margin-right:-0.5em , *- font-size:0 . In fact , minify your html or make diseapper white-space in html code and it works everywhere without hazardous styling and reset of it a level lower :) Maintenance is easier.